# How do I group radio buttons for separate fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, radio-button

I have a rails app that gives users assignments and prompts them via email to come back and note that their assignment is completed or take some other action. I have three different actions (remind me later, choose a different assignment, or get help from a coach) which are represented by three radio buttons. How do I group these so that the user can only choose one of the three actions at a time?

```
    <%= form_for(@assignment, :url => user_assignment_path(@user, @assignment)) do |a| %>
        <%= a.radio_button :next_reminder_date, value: (Date.today + 2) %> <h3>Remind me again in 2 days.</h3><br>
        <%= a.radio_button :coach_requested, true %> <h3>I'm stuck! Have a coach contact me.</h3><br>
        <%= a.radio_button :abandoned, true %> <h3>This sucks. Give me another assignment.</h3><br>

        <%= a.submit "Update assignment", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options. One would be to set the values using JavaScript. When any of the values is set, you can reset the other values. This won't work if a user doesn't have JavaScript so I'd recommend option 2.

Use something like this in your View:

```
radio_button_tag :next_action, :next_reminder_date
radio_button_tag :next_action, :coach_requested
radio_button_tag :next_action, :abandoned
```

Then in your Controller:

```
case params[:next_action]
when :next_reminder_date
  @assignment.next_reminder_date = Date.today + 2
when :coach_requested
  @assignment.coach_requested = true
when :abandoned
  @assignment.abondoned = true
end
```

I hope that helps.